# Generate random username based on full name php

Tags: php

I want to grab the first name in lowercase then concatenate the first two characters after the space and finally concatenate that with a random number from 0 to 100.
So if my name is `"Mike Test"` I want the output to be: `mikete3`

```
function random_username($string) {
    $pattern = " ";
    $firstPart = strstr(strtolower($string), $pattern, true);
    $secondPart = substr(strstr(strtolower($string), $pattern, false), 0, 3);
    $nrRand = rand(0, 100);

    $username = $firstPart.$secondPart.$nrRand;
    return $username;
}

echo random_username("Mike Test");
```

My function outputs "mike te84" and I don't know how to remove that space.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try this, always use trim to remove extra space.

```
function random_username($string) {
$pattern = " ";
$firstPart = strstr(strtolower($string), $pattern, true);
$secondPart = substr(strstr(strtolower($string), $pattern, false), 0,3);
$nrRand = rand(0, 100);

$username = trim($firstPart).trim($secondPart).trim($nrRand);
return $username;
}

echo random_username("Mike Test");
```

Comment: There's a shorter way to do this and with one less call to `trim()`.

Answer (score 1):

1. Convert all letters to lowercase with `strtolower()`.
2. Isolate the first word and the first two characters after the space.
3. Create and return a space-less string from the two isolated values and the randomly generated integer.

Code: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/kKH1P)) (leveraging [Spread Operator in Array Expression](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/spread_operator_for_array) from PHP7.4)

```
function random_username($string) {
    return vsprintf('%s%s%d', [...sscanf(strtolower($string), '%s %2s'), random_int(0, 100)]);
}

echo random_username("Mike Test"); // mikete25
```

An alternative syntax can declare variables to make it more intuitive/expressive. ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/gOnro))

```
function random_username($string) {
    sscanf(strtolower($string), '%s %2s', $first, $second);
    return sprintf('%s%s%d', $first, $second, random_int(0, 100));
}
```

Or apply the same behavior with `preg_replace()` where `\S` means any non-whitespace character: ([Demo](https://3v4l.org/vqjq0))

```
function random_username($string) {
    return preg_replace('/(\S+) (\S{2}).*/', '$1$2', strtolower($string)) . random_int(0, 100);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Regex solution

```
function random_username($string) {
    $nrRand = rand(0, 100);
    
    $string = strtolower($string);
    return preg_replace('/^(.+)\s(.{2}).+$/', '$1$2', $string, 1) . $nrRand;
}

echo random_username("Mike Test");
```

Answer (score -1):

Try:

```
function random_username($string) {
    $name = split("[ .-]", $string);
    $firstname = $name[0];
    $lastname = $name[1];

    $firstname = strtolower($firstname);
    $lastname = strtolower(substr($lastname, 0, 2));
    $nrRand = rand(0, 100);
    return $firstname . $lastname . $nrRand;
}

echo random_username("Mike Test");
```

Answer (score -1):

Simpler way

```
$username = substr(str_replace(' ','',strtolower($name)), 0, 5).rand(1,3);
```

Comment: This unexplained answer is not flexible enough for general use.  It is relying on the fact that the first word (in the asker's sample string) is 4 characters long.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this code to generate a random username based on the user's full name.

```
<?php
function generateUsername($fullName)
{
    $removedMultispace = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $fullName);

    $sanitized = preg_replace('/[^A-Za-z0-9\ ]/', '', $removedMultispace);

    $lowercased = strtolower($sanitized);

    $splitted = explode(" ", $lowercased);

    if (count($splitted) == 1) {
        $username = substr($splitted[0], 0, rand(3, 6)) . rand(111111, 999999);
    } else {
        $username = $splitted[0] . substr($splitted[1], 0, rand(0, 4)) . rand(11111, 99999);
    }

    return $username;
}

$username = generateUsername("Elon Musk");
echo $username;
?>
```

**Output:**

```
elonmusk74388
elon41960
elonmus77699
elonmus26248
elonmusk93154
elonmusk83467
elonm28690
elonmu79305
elonmu18227
elonmu28329
elon15113
elonmus38293
elonmusk77995
elonmusk77790
elonmu13349
elonmu73136
elonmus27741
elonmu72284
elon47465
elon85983
elonmus49720
```